# Mysql CSV load infile

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've got a CSV file with 9 columns and I have a MySQL table with 11 columns.

The CSV file looks like:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9
```

and the MySQL table looks like:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11
```

I need to get the script to ignore the two erroneous (but required) MySQL columns.

The mysql columns that need to be ignored in the import are: db_id & nice_date =)

This is what I have so far:

```
$sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "../csvtemp/test.csv" 
        INTO TABLE sample 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" 
            IGNORE 1 LINES'
;
```

Comment: Have you thought of using PHP fgetcsv() to read each line of the CSV file into an array?  Then you can implode the array into a query.  It's a bit more code than LOAD DATA, but it's sure to work right.

Comment: Another alternative - ALTER TABLE to remove the extraneous columns, LOAD DATA, then ALTER TABLE to add the columns back.

Comment: And I guess just for clarification, which has nine and which has eleven.  I think the narrative does not match the examples ;-)

Comment: The definition of your table is missing. Also don't you get an error back? That information is useful, too.

Comment: Sorry @RayPaseur , miles away! The mysql has 11 and the csv has 9 =)

unfortunately the CSV is over 100mb in size and no code I've seen can process as effectively as just straight mysql dump and the altertable is vaguely out of the question as the table can be updated at any time with more csv imports and it would be nice to keep the index_id the same

Comment: @KeithWhelpton: If you want help, you need to provide more information. If you need default values or re-map, check the syntax (especially at the end): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html, the part `SET col_name = expr`

Comment: @KeithWhelpton: I edited your question to point out what I find not constructive with it. Please check the edit.

Comment: @hakre there's no error produced, the data simply doesn't insert into the right DB columns due to the extra two that dont match the csv.

I also edited my question as per your suggestion =)

Comment: Perhaps you can ask the author of the CSV to add two dummy fields?

Comment: @RayPaseur, Its a lovely idea; I'm trying to keep everything as easy for the operator as possible however and just be able to stick the csv in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "../csvtemp/test.csv" 
        INTO TABLE sample 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" 
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9)'
;
```

The missing columns will be given their DEFAULT values, or else you can specify fixed values this way:

```
$sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "../csvtemp/test.csv" 
        INTO TABLE sample 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" 
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9)'
            SET col10 = 'abc', col11 = 'xyz'
;
```

Comment: I didn't inserted auto-increment field but when i insert for next time, it excludes some numbers. Ex: when i insert 4 rows, at first 1,2,3,4 and when i do it again the auto-increment fields are 8,9,10,11

Comment: Failed inserts still use id values. In general. don't worry about gaps between id values. Auto-increments are required to be unique, but are not required to be consecutive. They are not row numbers.

Comment: That's ok but is that an issue in our query..? Can it be corrected..?

Comment: It can be corrected if you specify values of your ids instead of letting the auto-increment generate them.

Comment: if so, there is an issue in "auto-increment" on "load data local infile".. because auto-increment doesn't need ids to be inserted(optional) when inserting and it won't give gaps on normal.. and if so it's better to read the file and insert mulitple values if i don't need gaps in ids..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use `LINES TERMINATED BY` (perhaps with `PHP_EOL`).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

To quote the manual page:

> If a line does not contain all fields, the rest of the columns are set
>   to their default values.