# Upload Bulk Data In Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am Uploading bulk data in mysql database it is taking 1 hour to upload 50000 md5

I want to Save uploading time;

I Am uploading data by csv file using `(<input type='file' />)`

Comment: _Nothing_ we can say if you do not provide any information about the details.

Comment: It took me about 1-1.5h to upload 13GB of data, so your connection is too weak or database server can't handle upload. Give us some more informations.

Comment: If you know that the file contains consistently-formed CSV (there is no standard, so you'll likely want to test extensively before importing over any production tables) you can skip PHP altogether and use MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE statement after uploading the data to the server.

Comment: Do u have any conditions in your query to update data then add index may help you to save time.

Comment: no i am uploading my data in my localhost  (centos os)  (8 gb ram)      ,  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)   is my code        and my query don't have any condition

Answer (score 0):

Ref. Link  [Mysql CSV load infile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012883/mysql-csv-load-infile)

You can try this as example

```
$sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "../csvtemp/test.csv" 
        INTO TABLE sample 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" 
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9)'
;
```

The missing columns will be given their DEFAULT values, or else you can specify fixed values this way:

```
$sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "../csvtemp/test.csv" 
        INTO TABLE sample 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" 
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9)'
            SET col10 = 'abc', col11 = 'xyz'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found solution of my question.
 I develop code for insert bulk data quickly in mysql database by dynamic query

before developing this query i was inserting 50000 md5 in 1 hour but after developing this query it is taking  1-2 second .
   this is my code.

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['uploadinvalid'])) // button name
{
$file_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];    
$temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$type=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
$error=$_FILES["file"]["error"];
$size=$_FILES["file"]["size"];
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="vaibhav123";
$database="userinfo";
$cid=mysql_connect($server,$user,$password) or die("Try Again");
mysql_select_db($database,$cid);
 $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
  $fst="yes"; 
  $query="insert into username (name) values "; // predefine query
  $count=0; // counter for count how much values have been added 
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
    $count++;
   $name=md5(trim($data[0]));
    if($fst=='yes') // check if fst== yes then don't use (,) comma
    {
    $fst="no";
    $query.="('$name')";  // append value with predefine query if first time append don't use  (,) comma
    }
    else
    $query.=",('$name')";   // append value and  use  (,) comma
    if($count==30000) //if counter==30000 query will execute         
   {
    mysql_query($query,$cid);
   $fst="yes";  //set fst=yes after execute query
    $query="";   //set query="" after execute query
    $count=0;     //set count=0 after execute query
   } 
    }
    mysql_query($query,$cid);  //execute query for remain values
    mysql_close($cid);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PhpMyadmin then you can try with first option otherwise you can use "
[BigDump: Staggered MySQL Dump Importer](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) " which is importing of large and very large MySQL Dumps

**First Option**

> When trying to import large SQL files into mysql using phpmyadmin, the
>   phpmyadmin documentation offers a few solutions, but I find the
>   easiest method to overcome this is…
>
> Find the config.inc.php file located in the phpmyadmin directory. In
>   my case it is located here:
>
> 1. C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\config.inc.php
>
> Find the line with $cfg['UploadDir'] on it and update it to:
>
> 1. $cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';
>
> Create a directory called ‘upload’ within the phpmyadmin directory.
>
> 1. C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\upload\
>
> Then place the large sql file that you are trying to import into the
>   new upload directory. Now when you go onto the db import page within
>   phpmyadmin console you will notice a drop down present that wasn’t
>   there before – it contains all of the sql files in the upload
>   directory that you have just created. You can now select this and
>   begin the import.
>
> If you’re not using WAMP on Windows, then I’m sure you’ll be able to
>   adapt this to your environment without too much trouble.

Comment: If you know that the file contains consistently-formed CSV (there is no standard, so you'll likely want to test extensively before importing over any production tables) you can skip PHP altogether and use MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE statement after uploading the data to the server.

Comment: i am creating a portal for user