# Import a CSV file into a MySQL table with PHP 5

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to import a whole CSV file (which was originally a CDR file and contains 108 fields) into a table of MySQL database with PHP 5. I use PDO.

In this line the import is made, but only the first line is loaded.

```
$AffectedRows = $pdo->exec("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$csvfile."' INTO TABLE `sample`    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  ;");
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the csv file ?

Comment: I notice you are using `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` - can you be certain that all lines in your csv file are terminated by '\r\n' - maybe the following lines are terminated by a NEWLINE character or LINEFEED?

Comment: You are using [tag:cdr] incorrectly. See its excerpt (shows upon hovering). What do you mean by CDR? http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/cdr Is it relevant to the question being asked?

Comment: Not only was the tag wrong, isn't a *.cdr file a CorelDraw file? Can't imagine using CorelDraw for that purpose.......

Comment: You can actually do this with the PHP MyAdmin GUI, just by importing a CSV.

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` is MySQL-specific, I edited the question to make clear that MySQL is the database being used. Next time please include this information.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012883/mysql-csv-load-infile if it helps solve your problem and come back to tell us the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the file, it didn't have the extension (.csv) but i need the option IGNORE 1 LINES and it doesn't work! when i add it "AffectedRows = $pdo -> exec ("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$csvfile."' INTO TABLE `cdr_StandAloneCluster_01_201209111313_29945` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;"); The table isn't charger any more!